# Angular Version 14: Getting 'pokemons' array of a trainer

Tags: json, angular, angular-services, http-get, subscribe

Good morning!

These days i've been working on a pokemon-based project.

My issue to solve right now is to solve the function located at service which gets the pokemons array of a trainer (function below):

```
  getPokemonsOfATrainer(nombreEntrenador: string){
    return this.http.get<Trainer>(`${this.apiUrl1}?fullName=${nombreEntrenador}`).pipe(
      map( (entrenador: Trainer) => {
        return entrenador.pokemons;
      })
    );
  }
```

My mocked JSON (example of 1 trainer), it's in the following format:

```
{
    "entrenadores": [
        {
            "fullName": "Alecs",
            "pokemons" : [
                {
                    "name":"Venusaur",
                    "nature": "Calm",
                    "attacks": [
                        {
                            "name":"Leech Seed",
                            "type":"Grass",
                            "style":"Attack"
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"Sleep Powder",
                            "type":"Grass",
                            "style":"Support"
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"Grass Knot",
                            "type":"Grass",
                            "style":"Attack"
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"Sludge Bomb",
                            "type":"Poison",
                            "style":"Attack"
                        }
                    ]                        
                }, 
                {
                    "name": "Skarmory",
                    "nature": "Impish",
                    "attacks": [
                        {
                            "name": "Slash",
                            "type": "Normal",
                            "style": "Attack"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Spikes",
                            "type": "Bug",
                            "style": "Support"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Brave Bird",
                            "type": "Flying",
                            "style": "Attack"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Rock Slide",
                            "type": "Rock",
                            "style": "Attack"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Registeel",
                    "nature": "Careful",
                    "attacks": [
                        {
                            "name": "Focus Blast",
                            "type": "Fighting",
                            "style": "Attack"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Hyper Beam",
                            "type": "Normal",
                            "style": "Attack"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Shadow Claw",
                            "type": "Dark",
                            "style": "Attack"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Rock Smash",
                            "type": "Rock",
                            "style": "Attack"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Uxie",
                    "nature": "Impish",
                    "attacks": [
                        {
                            "name": "Future Sight",
                            "type": "Psychic",
                            "style": "Support"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Memento",
                            "type": "Normal",
                            "style": "Support"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Dazzling Gleam",
                            "type": "Psychic",
                            "style": "Support"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Drain Punch",
                            "type": "Fighting",
                            "style": "Attack"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Gallade",
                    "nature": "Adamant",
                    "attacks": [
                        {
                            "name": "Hypnosis",
                            "type": "Psychic",
                            "style": "Support"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Night Slash",
                            "type": "Ghost",
                            "style": "Attack"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Brick Break",
                            "type": "Fighting",
                            "style": "Attack"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Close Combat",
                            "type": "fighting",
                            "style": "Support"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Would exist a proper way to get the pokemons of a trainer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `HttpClientTestingModule` and follow the standard way how to stub the response of http requests. For example, this one: https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/guides/http-request

Your test can look like:

```js
describe('suite', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule], // <- add 
    providers: [PokemonService],
  }).compileComponents());

  it('test', () => {
    // getting the service and httpMock
    const service = TestBed.inject(PokemonService);
    const httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    
    // subscribing to the result of the http request
    let actual: any;
    service.getPokemonsOfATrainer('trainer')
      .subscribe(value => actual = value);

    // stubbing the http request
    const req = httpMock.expectOne('<PUT_HERE_API_URL>?fullName=Alecs');
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    req.flush(mockedJson.entrenadores);
    httpMock.verify();

    // asserting that we got what expected
    expect(actual).toEqual(mockedJson.entrenadores.pokemons);
  });
});
```